# Navigation links doesn't working. The app is made in Next.js framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, export

I am working in Next.js framework. I've created a very simple site. In the header of site there is "home" and "about" navigation links. In development environment these both are working well but when I export the app with "npm run export" which then calls the "next export" it shows the following error:
`Error occurred prerendering /about: { Error: Cannot find module for page: /about`
 I can't understand why this happens to me! Please help :|.